# Button inside MapView is not visible

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with button's visibility inside MapView.

Layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPDATE DATA"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/updateMarkers"/>

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

When I initialize button (**updateDataButton**) like below
 (after initializing mapView) I got NullPointerException - button is null.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_fragment, container, false);

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume();

    updateDataButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.updateMarkers);
    updateDataButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();

    googleApiClient.connect();

    return view;
}
```

but when I initialize button before initializing mapView everythings seems to be ok, but button is not displaying. 
Do you have any idea about how to properly display button in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ad3luc.maps.AMain"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use a **RelativeLayout** and inside the layout put the **MapView** and a **Button** widget.
I have not an api key for use the maps but the *Button* display over the *MapView* widget without problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working exactly how I want :)